# Angularjs issue with jquery plugin in links with # navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using [this](https://codyhouse.co/gem/side-team-member-bio/) `jquery` plugin in a `angularjs` single page application.

The **main** block is in this menu :

`http://localhost:81/website/#/portfolio`

Which contains this block:

```
<li>
    <a href="#0" data-type="member-1">
        <!-- image tag goes here -->
    </a>
</li>
```

---

**The problem** is this : when I click on image (a tag) , angularjs redirect me to home page, because the link is `#0`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try wrapping whatever element is the root element for that plugin with ngNonBindable so that no binding happens within. I'm not sure if that will work, but you might give it a shot.